# Solve system of linear equations in RREF

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I need to solve a system of linear equations using rref. I need to put my answers in the following format:

[image]

I am assuming that they are two vectors, which one has a scalar s.

Could you help me out in solving this? Idk where to start.

The equation system is:

$$ x_1 + x_2 +  2x_3 = 2, \\
   6x_1 + 5x_2 + 3x_3 = -9. $$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Write the system of equations as a matrix equation:

$$\pmatrix{1 \;\;\;1 \;\;\;2 \\ 6 \;\;\;5 \;\;\;3}\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3}=\pmatrix{2 \\ -9}$$

and perform [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). If this is not enough to get you started, let me know in the comments below.

Comment: it got me started... I did Gaussian elimination... afterwards, I solved the system, that gave me: x1 = 7x3 - 19 and x2 = -9x3 +21.. I think I understand now..

Comment: Thanks for your help! It got me started, and made me come to my answer which was the vectors: [-19, 21, 0] + [7,-9,1]x3 Thanks!!!!

Comment: @JackGal Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your given system can be written as an augmented matrix
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
6 & 5 & 3 & -9
\end{array}\right]
$$
[Row-reducing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) allows us to write the system in [reduced row-echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & -7 & -19 \\
0 & 1 & 9 & 21
\end{array}\right]
$$
This matrix corresponds to the system
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrcr}
x_1 &&&-&7\,x_3 &=& -19 \\
     &&x_2&+&9\,x_3&=&21
\end{array}
Thus all solutions to our system are of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}-19+7\,x_3\\21-9\,x_3\\x_3\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}-19\\21\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}7\\-9\\1\end{bmatrix}x_3
$$

Comment: Thank you for your cleaner version of my solution! Did you use MathJax?