# System of linear equations to matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Use matrix transformations to solve the system
>   $$
> \begin{alignat}{15}
> 6x &{}+{}& 3y &{}+{}& 2z &{}+{}& 3u &{}+{}& 4v &{}={}& 6 & \\
> 4x &{}+{}& 2y &{}+{}& z &{}+{}& 2u &{}+{}& 3v &{}={}& 4 & \\
> 4x &{}+{}& 2y &{}+{}& 3z &{}+{}& 2u &{}+{}& v &{}={}& 4 & \\
> 2x &{}+{}& y &{}+{}& 7z &{}+{}& 3u &{}+{}& 2v &{}={}& 7
> \end{alignat}
> $$

Should I turn the matrix that I get after rewriting coefficients into RREF (row reduced echelon form) to make it as easy as it is possible to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the **Augmented Matrix** in RREF, you can easily check whether the system has solution and then solve starting from the bottom pivot.

You can find many other OP on this topic:

[Solve system of linear equations in RREF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656418/solve-system-of-linear-equations-in-rref)

Comment: I have probably stupid question. Is it always possible to reduce matrix to a RREF?

Comment: @JamesSmith Yes it is always possible and the number of pivots corresponds to the rank of the matrix